# jQuery UI Tabs - Tabs hide and show in IE on partial postback

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I use jQuery UI Tabs with ASP.NET Treeview and Gridview, and it works fine in normal browsers. With IE, however, the following thing occurs.

My tab looks smth like this:
[image]

The Treeview triggers a partial postback to update a panel, and the moment the postback happens, the tabs (Tree and List) disappear, so the picture is as follows:
[image]

And then, when the postback has happened, the tabs appear again. So, since the height changes, the whole picture seems to be "jumping".

This thing happens in IE7 and IE8.

Does anyone know what can cause it?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I thought my question might be confusing. The tabs as a whole jquery plugin do not hide&show, the problem concerns only the **header** part of the tabs.

**EDIT2**
Here's the markup and code:

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" >

    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#treeV" >Tree</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#listV" >List</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="common" class="listTree">
        <div id="treeV" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" >
            <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_OnSelectedNodeChanged" />
        </div>  

       <div id="listV" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"> 
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
       </div></div></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad() {
         $("#tabs").tabs({
             fx: { opacity: "toggle", duration: "slow" }
    });}

</script>
```

Comment: Please post markup and client-side code

Comment: Wors well for me in IE 9 switched to both IE8 and IE7 browser mode. jQuery version 1.6.4 and jQuery-UI 1.8.16.

Comment: @Yuriy Rozhovetskiy Maybe IE9 browser modes still differ somehow from IE8 and IE7. I use jQuery 1.8.16 and it jumps like hell. Thanks for trying anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Add client-side `pageLoad` function and move to it your tabs initialization code. Also, you don't need to cal this function explicitly. 
 Or subscribe for `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager`'s `endRequest` event and renew tabs in that event handler in additional to code executed on $(document).ready.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, I already have the pageLoad function on the client-side, so I just moved the tabs initialization there. Then I realized the endRequest event and tried to initialize there. Still the problem remains. What I noticed is that the tabs disappear **before** pageLoad() fires. I'm not sure what event I should catch in this case to initialize the tabs.

Comment: Also, I just thought that the tabs as a whole plugin do not disappear, what disappears is the header part of the tabs. I'll edit my question.